# AWS cognito refresh token issue in Nebular with Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nebular

I have a problem with my JWT token refresh,I need to refresh token if it's expired without login,
I saw a method inside NbAuthService called **refreshToken**.
I can't understand how to use it, I added that code inside my interceptor. Here is my code
In this code, it's not subscribe the refreshToken

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthJWTInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.authService.getToken().switchMap((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
      if (!token.isValid()) {
         this.authService.refreshToken('email').subscribe((newToken: any) => {
          console.log((newToken));
        });
        this.router.navigate(['auth']);
      }
      if (token) {
        const JWT = `${token.getValue()}`;
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: JWT,
          },
        });
      }
      return next.handle(req);
    });
  }

  protected get authService(): NbAuthService {
    return this.injector.get(NbAuthService);
  }
}
```

Here is my configuration code

```
NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.setup({
            name: 'email',
            clientId: environment.cognitoClientId,
            clientSecret: '',
            clientAuthMethod: NbOAuth2ClientAuthMethod.NONE,
            redirect: {
              success: '',
              failure: '',
            },
            defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
            defaultMessages: ['You have been successfully authenticated.'],
            authorize: {
              endpoint: environment.cognitoUrl + '/oauth2/authorize',
              redirectUri: environment.siteUrl + '/auth/callback',
              responseType: NbOAuth2ResponseType.TOKEN,
            },
            token: {
              endpoint: environment.cognitoUrl + '/oauth2/token',
              grantType: NbOAuth2GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
              requireValidToken: false,
              class: NbAuthCognitoToken,
            },
            refresh: {
              endpoint: environment.cognitoUrl + '/oauth2/token',
              grantType: NbOAuth2GrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN,
             },
          }),
        ],
      }).providers,
```

So what is the mistake I have done here, please help me to resolve this.

Comment: have you found a solution?